# Windows Media Player can not play anything in Windows 7 (MKV, AVI files)

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, matroska, video-codecs

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x86. I Installed KMPlayer and ZoomPlayer, ffdshow + coreAVC + Haali media splitter.

Everything about KMPLayer and Zoom player is ok, but Windows Media Player doesn't playany thing.

I can't install Windows Media Format 11 because of the error below:

> Not enough storage is available to process this command. Installation did not complete.

How can I fix that error?

---

I found a link on Videohelp forums that tells me I should change something after installing fddshow + CoreAVC + Haali media splitter codecs. Therefore I downloaded Win7 DSFilter Tweaker so I could play MKV files in Windows Media Player (although they should have worked with the software I installed above).

I think there is something wrong with this, in combination with Windows Media Player, because of my changes.

Pictures of my DSFilter Tweaker:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I disabled MP3 decoder DMO and by doing that Windows Media Player can play MP3 files again, but no MKV or AVI files.

Why is the MKV feature in picture 3 disabled?

What is the best configuration for Win7 DSFilter Tweaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fits your scenario exactly, but you might want to check out this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941384).

Comment: hi, thanks for answer. but your link was about windows server 2008 and vista. i am using windows 7.

Comment: @SilverLight: All three (Vista, 2008, 7) use the same type of codec (DirectShow). All three also support the newer Media Foundation codecs.